# Can't run Windows 7 Installer...Error reading from file

Tags: windows-7, installer, windows-installer, 64-bit

I am running Windows 7 (64 bit) Pro.  Whenever I try to install anything from a .msi file, I always receive the error:

```
"Error reading from file <path>/setup.msi.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it."
```

I've tried opening a command prompt as administrator and loading via the installer (msiexec) directly but still receive the same error.  I have administrator privileges and I checked the permissions on the file and I have full permissions.  I believe this is a 32 bit application so I am wondering if that has something to do with it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for posting this.  After hours of trying to figure this out I just did a little more research and got it.  Apparently my user was the only user with privileges on the folder and file containing the .msi file.  I added the SYSTEM user to have read and execute privileges on the folder containing the installer file and voila...it works and installs now.

Comment: Had the same problem, installer couldn't read from %temp%\folder\installer.msi (%temp%=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp). Added full rights for user SYSTEM on %temp% folder and installer ran just fine.

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) should indicate what file it is trying to access and if there are permission problems.

You could also check the event log and the most recent *.log files in the C:\Windows\Temp folder.